# Animation in highcharts

Tags: animation, highcharts

I am using highcharts in asp.net MVC4 for drawing graphs. Please let me know if I can use animation in the charts. I want my columns to progressively grow on load of page for 2 seconds.

Comment: I'm not sure about asp.net, but in Highcharts, just set `duration` of animation to 2000, see [api docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.animation).

Comment: Hi, Iam not able to add this property using the highchart dll in MVC4 controller. Can anyone please share the syntax